# Coveo card view on mobile with default template

Tags: coveo

I've been asked to disable the card view for a search result page. I know nothing about Coveo, but i have determined that for mobile the list view is prefered over card view. This is being implemented in a AEM 6.3 template.

In CoveoJsSearch.js, starting at line 17728 I have the following:

```js
         if (merged.responsiveComponents.isSmallScreenWidth()) {
             templates = _.filter(templates, function (tmpl) { return tmpl.layout == 'card'; });
             merged.currentLayout = 'list';
             this.layout = 'list';
         }
```

I changed these to list from card and it does what i want, but this looks JS file looks like it's 'compiled' from the front end framework. So what is the best way to ensure mobile users see a list view rather than a card view for search results.

Comment: Hi Mark, you might want to get in touch with our developers on [Answers.coveo.com](https://answers.coveo.com/questions/ask.html),  further details on the implementation might be required.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working through the tutorials, but I'll reach out.

Comment: I upgraded from V1 to V2 and this isn't an issue. The tutorials we not 100% clear, but so far things are working.

Comment: woudl you mind pointing us towards the documentaation, this way we can improve it?

Comment: When working through the tutorial, on step 6 (https://docs.coveo.com/en/420/javascript-search-framework/step-6---result-templates) it shows two CoveoResultList containers. It doesn't mention on a method to show or hide a result type at a breakpoint. 

As I mentioned I have this working, and I'm currently working a second implementation with AEM 6.3

Comment: normally, you should be able to set the view on the CoveoResultList component with data-layout="list", which will basically enforce this view on the specified tab. what version of the JSUI package are you on?

Comment: We're on V2 now, which solved this issue. Trying to launch today, just have path issues with the stand alone search.

Answer (score 1):

Coveo now provides easy control for this through your search page template:

https://connect.coveo.com/s/article/13748

So for your case (showing list view only at mobile), you'd likely want:

```
<div class="coveo-result-layout-section">
     <span class="CoveoResultLayout" data-mobile-layouts="list"></span>
</div>
```